Error HE0042: Could not launch app on iOS simulator using .NET MAUI with .NET 8.0
I'm working on a .NET MAUI project using .NET 8, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to launch my app on the iOS simulator with version is iOS 18.0.
xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys000 --stderr=/dev/ttys001 --terminate-running-process 17282796-8905-4573-AD40-A3D6EDACB042 com.edmatix.parent.prev -monodevelop-port 10000

However, I get the following error:
Simulator device failed to launch com.edmatix.parent.prev.
No such process
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
    Application launch for 'com.edmatix.parent.prev' did not return a process handle nor launch error.
    No such process
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.edmatix.parent.prev' on the device 'iOS 16.0 (20A360) - iPhone 14 Plus': simctl returned exit code 3

I'm running macOS 15.0.1 (24A348), and the simulator version is iOS 18.0.
Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Is it a default MAUI project?

Thank you for your input. Yes, this is a default .NET MAUI project, and I'm encountering this issue when attempting to launch it on the iOS simulator with iOS 18.0. Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

But why the error says on the device 'iOS 16.0?

I have verified that the issue occurs on both iOS 16.0 and iOS 18.0 simulators. Despite the error message referencing iOS 16.0, the same issue persists when attempting to launch the app on the iOS 18.0 simulator. Any insights or suggestions for further troubleshooting would be appreciated.

can you launch the simulator with XCode?
